# How to write a query in morphia?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, morphia

I am using `Morphia 1.3.2` and using `geoWithin` as `Filter Operator`. How can I convert the following `MongoDB` query to `Morphia`?

```
db.tbl_user.find( { 'currentLocation.loc': { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [-122.2407038,47.7735104] ,10 / 3963.2 ] } } } )
```

I followed the documentation but it's only showing `near` interface. Is there any way to achieve `within` in morphia?